# ¿Hay algún intellisense o autocompletado para Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Me gustaría saber si para Eclipse existe alguna extensión que sea como el intellisense del Visual Studio Code, para auto-completar el código mas fácilmente, (estoy harto de darle a CRTL + ESPACIO).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En Eclipse, en `Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist` puedes configurarlo.

Es posible que no te esté funcionando rápido (a veces tarda) o que tengas modificado el tiempo de activación.

En principio el `.` es el activador por defecto. De todos modos, te pego un pantallazo para que veas la opción.

[image: Captura de pantalla de Eclipse]

Por otra parte, puedes también revisar la configuración de las sugerencias que quieres:

[image: Opciones avanzadas]

Recuerda también activar los `Natures` y `Facets` de tu proyecto a proyecto `Java` para asegurarte que todo funciona con normalidad. En `Projet > properties`

[image: Eclipse project Natures]